# Android - starting IntentService frequently

Tags: android, performance, android-service

In my application, a single instance of a class acts like a state machine. Many activities wants to receive updates on the state of this object. The state of this object itself is updated from data from a broadcast of some primitive information.

I have implemented it this way.
I registered a broadcast receiver in the manifest file which receives the primitive information and then starts an IntentService just passing the received information.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent update_service = new Intent(context, StateMachineUpdateService.class);
    update_service.putExtra(PRIMITIVE, intent.getDoubleExtra(PRIMITIVE, 0));
    context.startService(update_service);
}
```

The StateMachineUpdateService keeps an instance and updates it:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        statemachine.update(intent.getDoubleExtra(PRIMITIVE, 0));
        Intent broadcast = new Intent(STATE_MACHINE_UPDATE);
        broadcast.putExtra(STATE_MACHINE_STATE, statemachine.get_state());
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is an more elegant way to achieve this. I am wondering if starting an IntentService (which in turn will start a separate thread) is something I should try to avoid. The primitive broadcast is sent about 10 times in a second.

#### Side-question:

let us say statemachine.update takes so much time that the next broadcast has arrived, I would like to ignore those broadcasts. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a singleton object that requires serialized access to its members, one way to go is to use a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) and schedule incoming work on it from your receiver or wherever else work may originate.  The HandlerThread will process everything (runnable or message) in the order it was received (just like the Android main thread).

If you want to skip incoming items of work, you can record the receive time of the work and compare it to the actual time it's being executed, and skip it if the some threshold has been exceeded.

Comment: you cannot instantiate a `HandlerThread` inside a `BroadcastReceiver` because of its lifecycle, `IntentService` internally uses  a `HandlerThread` so OP's approach seems to be right

Comment: Right, you can instead instantiate it as a singleton from within Application.

Comment: fair enough, but using Application object always smells to me... you could do everything in it, so what Services would be for? (except IPC)

Comment: Application is very frequently used for init of singletons.  IntentService is best for times when you have an item of work that may take an unknown amount of time and must be separate from the main thread and any activity.

Comment: speaking of Application object: do you by any chance know which Application i am in when app uses different processes ("android:process" attribute in <service> or <receiver> for example)? (except low level /proc tricks)

Comment: There is one Application object created for each process in the app.

Comment: exactly but there is no way to find out which is which, for example i have one Service created in different process so `MyApplication#onCreate` will be called twice: first for a "normal" app and the second hosting my service and i need to know which is which. i tried to find some API for that but miserably failed

Comment: You can query ActivityManager to get the name of the currently running process if you want to do something in Application.onCreate only for certain processes.

Answer (score 0):

Starting IntentService takes 1-15 ms on my 1 GHz phone. As it is created on UI Thread 10 calls can take even 100 ms which is too much (user will experience lag). You should consider using Hanlder with WorkerThread. You can check how IntentService use this solution and implement it in your case.